# Request body is empty on POST

Tags: java, android, node.js

Created an android app which posts data to a nodejs server.

The nodejs server is a simple http web server running

```
var http = require('http');

module.exports = http.createServer(function (req, resp) {
console.log("Request received!");
  resp.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'});

  if (req.method == 'POST') {
        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
        });
        req.on('end', function () {
            console.log("Body = " + body);
            // use POST

        });
    }    
});
```

The client (Android app) sends a post request using:

```
        URL url = new URL(endpoint);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getString());
        writer.close();
        os.close();
```

The getString() method is defined as:

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
root.put("test", "Testing");
return root.toString();
```

I receive the request on the server, but the body is empty.

I tried using express with bodyParser and I got the same result. This is with the older version of express. Even with the latest version of express, I had the same problem. In this case, I had to include the bodyParser module separately and call bodyParser(). In both the old and new versions, I called "req.body" (Which was also empty)

Any ideas?? Not sure why the body is not getting populated with the json string.

Comment: I don't do node.js, but shouldn't you need to send the correct `Content-Type` with your POST from the client? `conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Comment: or "application/json" I suppose.

Comment: If you've verified that you are getting inside your if statement, have you tried delaying the call to `resp.writeHead()` until inside your `req.on('end')` callback?

Comment: Something else you may try is use a tool like Wireshark to check what is or isn't being sent on the connection.

Comment: I can get the client to send the test data to the server by doing two things: 1. as @BrianRoach suggests, set the `Content-Type` header field. 2. after `os.close()`, I added this line: `InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();` _Why_ this helps? I have no idea. But the server receives the JSON data, and the client throws a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`. I didn't get anywhere trying to fix it -- it was either no communication between server/client, or this. Good luck!

Comment: Tried changing content type, reading input stream from connection as suggested, calling resp.writeHead inside the req.on('end') callback. I still see the problem. Thank you for the suggestions though!